# How to get number of records created in last 2 minutes

Tags: datetime, laravel-4

I have successfully get the records crated in today using following code.

```
$carcount = Car::where('username', '=', $username)
                    ->whereRaw('created_at >= CURRENT_DATE')
                    ->whereRaw('created_at < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY')
                    ->count();
```

but i canot get the records crated in last minute using following code.

```
$carcount = Car::where('username', '=', $username)
                        ->whereRaw('created_at >= CURRENT_DATE')
                        ->whereRaw('created_at < CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE')
                        ->count();
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is what you need. You are adding 1 minute to the beginning (midnight) of the current day.

Comment: hi, look like i have some weird problm.

Comment: if i use this sql in my client it work SELECT * FROM cards WHERE bought_at > addtime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '-8:04:00')

Comment: but i set to SELECT * FROM cards WHERE bought_at > addtime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '-0:04:00') it not work

Comment: Look like some kind of time zone problem

Comment: Maybe I need to set both server and laravel in to same time zone?

Comment: Just run a simple `SELECT` to see what `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives you, then you can confirm if the issue is a timezone difference

Comment: thanks anyway i have set the both server and laravel in to same time zone